# When coil whine can be considered as normal?

Tags: laptop, desktop-computer, noise

Is [**coil whine**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coil_noise) always a warning sign of a hardware failure, or completely normal under high stress?
My computer has only produced audible coil noise when running a game with uncapped frame rate, simple 2D menus can easily reach thousands of frames per second. Oddly, *I've never* heard coil whine when playing a modern, graphically advanced and demanding title.

Comment: Seems like your Wikipedia link has the answer.

Comment: It's definitely not a sign of hardware failure.  Some devices make noise even when not under above average stress. Many old televisions do! And some ACDC adaptors. Sometimes the noise can be too high for most people to pick up, but  many children, and people with sensitive hearing, and spock, would hear it.

Comment: If you open the desktop up you might be able to locate the exact bit of circuitry  / the exact coil(s), where the noise is coming from.